# How can I use nested templates with Smarty?

Tags: php, templates, nested, smarty

I tried some ways, but they either threw a SmartyException or the nested templates didn't have access to the variables I assigned in my PHP file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `{include}` directive.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl

Comment: Mm. I wonder how I passed this. I Googled "nested", "template in template", etc. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Smarty 3 there is a better way to do this.
Check out the [Template Inheritance](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.template.inheritance.tpl). This is much more convenient than `{include}`.

Answer (score 0):

Smarty 3
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.create.template.tpl

You should use

```
string createTemplate(string template,
                      string cache_id,
                      string compile_id,
                      object parent);
```

Where parent param is your parent template

> parent is an optional parameter. It is
>   an uplink to the main Smarty object, a
>   user-created data object or to another
>   user-created template object. These
>   objects can be chained. The template
>   can access only variables assigned to
>   any of the objects in the parent
>   chain.